# Select highcharts DOM with jQuery after redraw()

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have an application using highcharts in which i wrote custom methods to add some functionalities. These methods are callable by listening(.click mostly) DOM elements inside highcharts chart.

It works perfect, but if redraw() is called i can not select highcharts DOM elements anymore. How can i avoid that? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I read it, but thought my post was good enough, sorry. I'll expand a little bit.

I've something like this:
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(this.options);
$(".highcharts-title").click(function(){
       //some code
})

It works, but when i call chart.redraw() the .click() listener stop working.

Comment: Oh well, should i repost it with the added info? :(

Comment: No need to repost, you can edit your own question with more details and preferably some code so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redraw() is recreating the dom elements that you have added the click events to.  So, the click events are lost.  You need delegated events.  Instead of

```
$(".highcharts-title").click(function(){ //some code });
```

use

```
$( "#container" ).on( "click", ".highcharts-title", function() { //some code });
```

assuming `#container` is your chart container.  You can attach to `body` if you won't have the container created at the time of your event defintion.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks very much, it solved my problem. I finally understood the "on" method. :)